# Rails: How to pass array from view to controller with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. What I'm trying to do is to design an order system. It lists a bunch of items and each item is followed by a select box so that people can choose the number that they want to order. My question is how to pass this count[] array and the corresponding item id from view to controller using button_to. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to item.name, item %>
      <%= select_tag 'count[]', options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5])%>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to 'Place Order', orders_confirm_path, method: :post, params: { ??? } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this using form like below

```
<%= form_tag orders_confirm_path, method: :post do %>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, value: item.id %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to item.name, item %>
          <%= select_tag 'count[]', options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5])%>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to 'Place Order' %>
<% end %>
```

Now you can find on controller `params[:count]` `params[:item_id]`

Hope to help

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to also keep the item id information with the count and pass them back to controller?

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You use the tag multi-select.

example in your view. For can select multi with ctrl + click at item:

```
<%= form_tag orders_confirm_path, method: :post %>
<label>select more than one with ctrl + click at item</label>
<p><%= select_tag :items, Item.all.collect {|item| [item.name, tem.id]}, {prompt: "Select item"}, multiple: true %></p>

<p><%= button_to 'Place Order'%></p>
```

and your controller you can receive the parameters in this way:

def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:items])
    if @order.save
     code ...
    else
      code ...
    end
end